# Eclipse CDT header files don't have "Paths and Symbols"

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I'm using Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2).
Properties - C/C++ General - Paths and Symbols.

This is set up for the project to define symbols controlling conditional inclusion.
It works OK for the c/cpp files, but the header files don't seem to see them, so all the conditionally included code is greyed out.
Looking at the properties of the header file itself, it doesn't show any symbols, and there is no way to add them.

How do you get the header files to respect the symbols?

This isn't a compilation issue, it's just a question of the editing environment recognising the right types etc.

Comment: In the indexer configuration menu, did you select to use the active build configuration ? Or to rebuild the indexer ?

Comment: I've tried changing the indexer config to include header files in all possible forms, e.g. "Index source and header files open in editor" but the file still doesn't recognise the symbols. The problem seems to be more fundamental, i.e. no h file has an entry for symbols in its own Properties / C/C++ general / Paths and Symbols.